# Create Dynamic elements or list

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I have a brain fart here so I'm gonna ask for help. I'm building a weather app, onload it will take your current location and you will have the option to search for other cities. When you search for other cities they will be displayed on the side. I got everything working but I challenged myself to do it differently and now I'm stuck. This is what I have so far. DIV is already hardcoded in HTML where I am attaching the cities and is working perfectly fine. What I want is to generate the DIV or UL where it will hold the cities and inside to insert the cities. If I do a function to generate the DIV than I will have an error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null for the list of cities.

I work with MVC pattern and here is some of the code.

```
export const elements = {
  searchForm: document.querySelector(".search-form"),
  searchInput: document.querySelector(".search-form--input"),
  searchList: document.querySelector(".container"),
  searchCityList: document.querySelector(".city_list")
};
export const getInput = () => {
  return elements.searchInput.value;
};
export const clearInput = () => {
  elements.searchInput.value = "";
};

const controlSearch = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const input = getInput();
  console.log(input);
  renderResult(input);
  clearInput();
};

// Add Event Listeners
const form = elements.searchForm;
form.addEventListener("submit", controlSearch);

export const renderSearch = () => {
  const html = `
  <div class="city_list">
  // ----RESULT WILL GO HERE ----
  </div>
  `;
  elements.searchList.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);
};

export const renderResult = input => {
  const html = `
    <div class="list">
        <div class="city">${input}</div>
  </div>

    `;
  elements.searchCityList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html);
};
```

THIS WILL BE FROM ANOTHER FILE

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="submit" class="search-form">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="search-form--input"
      placeholder="Search City"
      required
    />
    <button type="submit" class="search-form--button">Add City</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- <div class="city_list"></div> --> If you uncomment this the code will work but the idea is to be dynamically generated.
```

When I generate renderSearch hardcoded in HTML I don't have error is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `import { elements } from './base';` in your second file

Comment: It is imported, I didn't include here. I just wanted to narrow the focus for the approach.

Comment: Your problem says that elements.searchList is Null. I don't see how you get that value. So I guess you need to start looking for a problem in the place where you set searchList in elements object.

Comment: If you delete `searchView.renderSearch();` and put `<div class="city_list"></div>` in the html file the app will work perfectly fine. But I would like to generate that dynamically. So if I run the code like above I won't get `searchView.renderResult(state.search.results);` generated. I have to figure out how to wait or check if city_list is available so I can render the cities inside...

Comment: I have edited the code files above.